# How to pass &auml; in xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am using a payment gateway to send xml via CURL. I am getting the following error when I use an XML Validator:

> Errors in the XML document: The entity "auml" was referenced, but not
>   declared.

So I understand the problem lies with the ä, however I am unsure on how to fix this using PHP.

Here is the xml request I am passing:

```
    <request type='payer-new' timestamp='XXXXXX'>
      <merchantid>XXXXXXXXX</merchantid>
      <orderid>XXXXXXXXX</orderid>
      <payer type='Business' ref='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'>                      
        <firstname>X&auml;xxxx</firstname>         
        <surname>x&auml;xxxxxx</surname>
        <address>
          <line1>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line1>
          <line2>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line2>
          <city>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</city>
          <postcode>XXXXXXXXXXXX</postcode>
          <country code='FI'>Finland</country>
        </address>
        <phonenumbers>
          <home>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</home>
        </phonenumbers>
        <email>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</email>
      </payer>                       
      <sha1hash>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sha1hash>
    </request>
```

I wrap htmlentities around all of the variables going into the request like so:

> ".htmlentities($_SESSION['W_CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME'], ENT_QUOTES,
>   "UTF-8")."

Is there a way that will work with all kinds of characters / names / places etc that contain these characters?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Don’t use `htmlentities`, but `htmlspecialchars` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: Technically, you use the wrong parameters with that function. See the `ENT_XML1` flag for that function. But there is more, I left an answer that gives you another suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

`&auml;` is an HTML entity code, not a generic XML one.

Generic XML only understands three named entities: `&amp;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

If you want to use any other named entities such as `&auml;`, those entities must be defined in the XML schema definition. Some standardised XML dialects have schemas which define named entities, but most do not, and if you don't have a schema, then you definitely won't be able to use any named entities.

So instead of using named entities in XML, it is generally better to use numeric entities. These take the form of `&#1234;`, where `1234` is the character code for the character you want. For a auml character, the code you need is `&#228;`. Note that these numeric entity codes can also work fine in HTML.

You can find a list of some of the more useful character codes here: http://www.econlib.org/library/asciicodes.html

Annoyingly, there isn't a standard PHP function that can produce these numeric XML entities. The `htmlentities()` and `html_special_chars()` functions are not suitable, as they produce named entities. So we have to write our own.

You'll need to use the `ord()` function to get the character code, but be aware of multi-byte characters. There is actually a reasonable attempt at an `xmlentities()` function in the comments on [the manual page for `htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which you could try. I know other implementations exist, though.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense

Comment: > I know other implementations exist, though.
please, share it with us also. That mentioned xmlentities() function really fails on multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 3):

I created such function for XML strings safe replacing:

```
     /**
     * Safe symbols escaping for XML. It's very similar to htmlspecialschars for html + mysql.
     * @param string $string
     * @return string
     */
    public static function xmlentities(string $string): string
    {
        return  htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8', true);
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
        $str = 'Dafür hörten "der Relativen Schw&amp;auml;che&amp;ldquo;-Entwicklung gegen&amp;uuml;ber den Wall Street';
        $str = static::xmlentities($str);
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
            <set>'.$str.'</set>
            </urlset>';
```

**Explanation:**

- ENT_XML1 set's the list of symbols accepted for XML documents
- 'UTF-8' sets the charset so ä and other German/national symbols becomes accepted as a symbol
- true -- the last TRUE parameter makes converting safe sins it often happens that incoming string has already some htmlspecialchars precessed symbols (e.g. during the loading from DB or getting from the API)

Remember to put charset declaration to the document header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or to set some other charset for htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is you have an XML document that is using HTML entities to encode things. An XML Validator knows nothing about HTML-specific entities, and so will choke.

I would hope that there is an XSD (schema) for the XML; it should really be declared in the root tag with an xmlns declaration and possibly with a xsi:schemaLocation too. This XSD file would be the right place to xsd:import the html entities that would enable your validator to validate correctly. There should also be an <?xml vers... > tag as the first line.

That said, I suspect that the receiving application won't care what the validator says, and that your response file is probably just fine, assuming the receiver knows about html entities too.

If not, you need to decode the html entities into actual utf8 characters, but probably do so just on the text elements of the DOM (e.g. the content of <email> not the whole text). Doing this with php's html_entity_decode() would seem reasonable. If you do this you *definitely* need the <?xml> tag to include the file charset.

HTH

Comment: Thanks. I will try the decode option and let you know how I get on. I am simply passing the xml into CURL so should be simple enough. Most of the data is passing through correctly and it is just these chars that are giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

> I wrap htmlentities around all of the variables going into the request like so: ...

There is your problem. You're creating the XML string "by hand". Not that it wouldn't be possible to do so, it's just easy to make mistakes by doing so. One hint could be the name of the function you use already, it starts with "`html`" which is not *XML*.

Anyway, before discussing in depth to which extend interpolating strings can cause troubles for creating XML and when such problems arise, it's much easier to use an XML library to create the XML.

An XML libary allows you to encode all data properly (so you won't see such errors) and with ease. In PHP there are normally three:

- **SimpleXML**
- **DOM**
- **XMLWriter**

Take the one you can work best with.

Alternatively you can verify that the XML you created "by hand" is well-formed *before* you send it to the remote service, by use of one of the following XML libraries as they are also XML parsers:

- **SimpleXML**
- **DOM**

Q&A material on how to create an XML document with either of these already exists on this website - even with examples and comments on them - so I don't duplicate such content in my answer. Same for the XML validation.

---

Example of an XML preset (pattern) of a request of which some parameters are set. Here with *SimpleXML*:

```
$pattern = <<<REQUEST_PATTERN
<request type='payer-new' timestamp='XXXXXX'>
    <merchantid>XXXXXXXXX</merchantid>
    <orderid>XXXXXXXXX</orderid>
    <payer type='Business' ref='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'>
        <firstname></firstname>
        <surname></surname>
        <address>
            <line1>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line1>
            <line2>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line2>
            <city>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</city>
            <postcode>XXXXXXXXXXXX</postcode>
            <country code='FI'>Finland</country>
        </address>
        <phonenumbers>
            <home>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</home>
        </phonenumbers>
        <email>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</email>
    </payer>
    <sha1hash>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sha1hash>
</request>
REQUEST_PATTERN;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($pattern);
$xml->payer->firstname = 'Äpfel';
$xml->payer->surname = 'Wachsen-Überirdisch';

# ...

// just an assumed way on how you would pass the XML string
// to the API via CURL (here as HTTP POST request body)
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
```

The XML that would be passed to the remote service would always(*) be XML encoded in a proper way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request type="payer-new" timestamp="XXXXXX">
    <merchantid>XXXXXXXXX</merchantid>
    <orderid>XXXXXXXXX</orderid>
    <payer type="Business" ref="XXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        <firstname>&#xC4;pfel</firstname>
        <surname>Wachsen-&#xDC;berirdisch</surname>
        <address>
            <line1>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line1>
            <line2>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</line2>
            <city>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</city>
            <postcode>XXXXXXXXXXXX</postcode>
            <country code="FI">Finland</country>
        </address>
        <phonenumbers>
            <home>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</home>
        </phonenumbers>
        <email>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</email>
    </payer>
    <sha1hash>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sha1hash>
</request>
```

(*) there are some rare circumstances where this would not be the case, but they should not play any role for this example: The SimpleXML library requires properly UTF-8 encoded strings to work.

Comment: That sounds like it could be very helpful. I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 1):

I have suffered same issue and i have resolves issue.

```
$str = 'Dafür hörten "der Relativen Schw&amp;auml;che&amp;ldquo;-Entwicklung gegen&amp;uuml;ber den Wall Street';

echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8', true);
```

I hope,this is usefull and it's working